# How to estimate a Gaussian mixture model with the EM algorithm in SAS?

Tags: sas, models, gaussian

I am trying to fit a univariate Gaussian Mixture Model with the EM algorithm. But I only found a package in R (mclust). Does anybody know an equivalent proc step in SAS 9.3?

Answer (score 0):

Check out PROC FMM (Finite Mixture Models).  I believe that does what you are looking for.

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/68162/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_fmm_overview01.htm

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have already checked it out. But I can't find the option with respect to the EM algorithm.

Comment: You are right, it only has ML and MCMC.  Can you use either of those?

Comment: No, unfortunately not... But it's a quite popular approach. Therefore I am a little bit confused that it is not offered in SAS.